# Scss файл _part.scss?

Tags: css, scss, less

Подскажите, есть ли в less аналог _part.scss. Гугл ответа не дал. В вёрстке использую gulp, отсюда и вопрос.

Comment: В смысле аналог? Что мешает добавить файл _less.scss ?

Comment: Уже разобрался. И как вы указали тож не лучший вариант. В gulpfile.js настраиваешь, как надо и всё чудно начинает работать. А аналога  '_' в less вообще нет оказывается.